# Kali Linux Stuck after installing on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, installation, virtual-machine, kali-linux, reinstall

I Installed Kali Linux on VirtualBox

after finishing installation it rebooted and stucked 
and I can run Kali even I deleted and installed again new downloaded ISO

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The first install can bit a bit tricky

You generally did not properly install GRUB boot loader. GRUB is a Multiboot boot loader. Boot loader is the first software program that runs when a computer starts.

So, when you are prompted during installation to:

> install the GRUB boot loader on a hard disk

You must select yes and click continue.

After this, you will be again prompted, to select GRUB boot loader install location.

Select your hard disk (That Virtual box created) and click continue.